# Sum where value is x

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do you get the sum of all values of A if it has "foo" in column B?
In the example below the sum should be 8.

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

try this

`=SUMIF(B:B,"foo",A:A)`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to sum a range of cell, as in your example:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B5, "foo", A1:A5)
```

[Syntax: SUMIF(range, criteria, sum_range)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)